# ubuntu dose not run (even loading page)

Tags: grub2

I have Asus N552VW and non of the versions doesn't run that means it stay on a black page or loading page and doesn't do anything  more.

but when I add this code to grub ubuntu will run but when I restart laptop this code will removed from grub and i have to add this again :

```
nouveau.modeset=0 pci=noaer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it to grub permanently by editing the configuration files.

`sudo vim /etc/default/grub`

Edit this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.modeset=0 pci=noaer quiet splash"
```

Save then run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: when i do it and restart my laptop i get this eror: (a start job is running for detect the avileble GPUs and deal whit any system changes )

Comment: change the above mentioned line to read exactly like the way you edit the grub entry to make it boot. Or is this a new problem?